# configure dns name sharepoint 2010

Tags: server

i have a site in sharepoint 2010 with address http://server001:7007/portal, how rename site to http://library:7007/portal.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to change the URL for the entire web application, or just a singe site collection within the web application? Do you have other sites that want to stay on http://server001:7007 ?

Comment: yes, have  http://server001:7007/itportal

Comment: i want to change url for the entire web application server001:7007/ to library:7007/

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL of the entire web application, you can do one of two things here:

1. Add an alternate access mapping to the new address for one of the zones for the web application
2. Destroy and recreate the web application on the new address

To do the first one of these, within Central Administration, under the Application Management area, select Configure Alternate Access Mappings, then click Edit Public URLs, select the alternate access mapping collection (i.e. the web application for which you want to add a URL and add a new URL (http://library:7007). You'll also need to add a binding for the URL within IIS Manager as well as SharePoint only does this for you for the default zone.

To do the second, you'll want to detach the existing databases that contain data for the web application, delete the current web application, create a new web application on the correct URL, then attach the content databases you attached initially. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff628582(v=office.14).aspx for the process. Note that PowerShell is the more reliable way to perform these operations.